# How to get my program to choose a new random number with each iteration of the loop? -Magic 8 ball

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a magic 8 ball program In python. I got it to go through the loop once correctly but It doesn't choose a new random number each time it goes through the loop. It keeps giving Positive Answers which is good but not optimal

I think it might have something to do with the way I defined my functions but I can't figure out how to get it to call the function each time.

```
from time import *
import random


def roll():
    ball = random.randint(1, 20)
    return ball


def isgood(ball):
    if ball >= 10:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def isneutral(ball):
    if 15 >= ball > 10:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def isbad(ball):
    if 20 >= ball > 15:
        return True
    else:
        return False


affirm = ("It is certain.", "It is decidedly so.", "Without a doubt.", "Yes - definitely.", "You may rely on it.",
          "As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.", "Signs point to yes.")

neutral = ("Reply hazy, try again.", "Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.", "Cannot predict now.",
           "Concentrate and ask again.")

bad = ("Don't count on it.", "My reply is no.", "My sources say no.", "Outlook not so good.", "Very doubtful.")

shake = 'y'
print("I am a magic 8 Ball")
print("Give me a shake to get your Mystical Answer...")
print("Would you like to shake the 8 ball?")
shake = input('y/n ')
shake = shake.lower()
sleep(0.5)
while shake == 'y':
    if isgood:
        sleep(0.5)
        print(random.choice(affirm))
        print("Shake again?")
        shake = input('y/n ')
        if shake == 'n':
            print("Goodbye!")

    elif isneutral:
        sleep(0.5)
        print(random.choice(neutral))
        print("Shake again?")
        shake = input('y/n ')
        if shake == 'n':
            print("Goodbye!")

    elif isbad:
        sleep(0.5)
        print(random.choice(bad))
        print("Shake again?")
        shake = input('y/n ')
        if shake == 'n':
            print("Goodbye!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. You never actually make a roll with `roll()`. Make a roll by doing:

```
number = roll()
```

after the line `while shake == 'y':`

2. You never actually call your `isgood()`,`isneutral()`, and `isbad()` functions. The way you're doing it, you're basically checking to see if the function exists

Do this by turning:

```
if isgood:
```

to

```
if isgood(number):
```

and do the same with how you call `isneutral` and `isbad`.

Edit:

just figured out a third. Your `isgood` function is checking if the number is `>= 10`, while it should check if the number `<=10`

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is not calling your functions. Add parentheses after the function name to call the function. That is; not `isgood`, but rather `isgood(last_roll_value)`.

Likewise, you do not seem to be invoking `roll()` every loop iteration.

Try adding last_roll_value = roll() at the top of your loop.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense though